# Include extra line when using newpage in longtable

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to change the `longtable` environment to always produce this row as a first row of cells:

```
\begin{tabular}
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector & Link \\
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is shown below, using the `tabular` environment instead of `longtable`.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\tabpageskip}{
                        \end{tabular}%
                        \newpage%
                        \noindent  \begin{tabular}[h]{l p{5cm} p{5cm} c c} 
                        \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector ? & Link \\%
                        \\%
                        \hline%
                        }%

\begin{document}


\noindent \begin{tabular}[h]{l p{5cm} p{5cm} c c} 
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector & Link \\
\\
\hline
\\
\texttt{?} & \texttt{?\textcolor{blue}{<commando>}} & {Het opzoeken van \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} commando's} && {$\leftarrow$} 
\\
\\
\texttt{apropos()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{apropos(}"\textcolor{cyan}{<commando>}"\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {(Deel van een) commando opzoeken} &  & {$\leftarrow$} \\
\\
\\
\texttt{as.table()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{as.table(}\textcolor{cyan}{<array>}\textcolor{red}{)}} & {\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{R}} vertellen dat je de gegevens als een tabel wil lezen: read \texttt{as.table()}!} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$} \\
\\
\\
\texttt{barplot()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{barplot(}\textcolor{cyan}{<functie>},} \texttt{\textcolor{green}{col=c(}\textcolor{red}{"<kleur>",...}\textcolor{green}{)}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Barplot maken (histogram, maar dan kolommen {apart}) Verschillende kleuren\label{anchor.kleurspec} instellen met de \textbf{engelse} namen, bijv.: \texttt{"brown"}} &  &  \\
\\
\\
\texttt{binom.test()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{binom.test(}\textcolor{cyan}{<tabel>},}  \texttt{\textcolor{green}{p=<waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Gesorteerde data tabel onderwerpen aan binomiaal test Hypothetische kans op succes (nulhypothese)} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$} \\
\\
\\
\texttt{c()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{c(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},\textcolor{cyan}{ <getal>},\textcolor{red}{...}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Handmatig een array maken. Voor langere getallen, gebruik \texttt{array()}} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$} \\
\tabpageskip
\\
\texttt{colSums()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{colSums(}\textcolor{cyan}{<functie>}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Optellen van kolommen van een matrix. Voor rijen, gebruik: {\texttt{rowSums()}$\rightarrow$}} & $\surd$ &  \\ 
\\
\\
\texttt{dbinom()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{dbinom(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},} \texttt{\textcolor{green}{size=<waarde>},}  \texttt{\textcolor{red}{prob=<waarschijnlijkheid>}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Kans op deze waarde bij zovaak proberen kans op succes} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$} \\ 
\\
\\
\texttt{expand.grid()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{expand.grid(}}  \texttt{\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>}:\textcolor{green}{<getal>},\textcolor{red}{...}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Aftellen meerdere dobbelstenen Minimale en maximale getal voor je `dobbelsteen'} &  & {$\leftarrow$} \\
\\
\\
\texttt{file.choose()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{file.choose(}"\textcolor{cyan}{<bestand>}"\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Bestanden laden in \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}}} && {$\leftarrow$} \\
\\
\\
\texttt{help()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{help(}\textcolor{cyan}{<commando>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Het opzoeken van \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} commando's} && {$\leftarrow$} \\
\\
\\
\texttt{hist()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{hist(}\textcolor{cyan}{<functie>},}  \texttt{\textcolor{green}{breaks=}\textcolor{red}{<getal>},} \texttt{\textcolor{violet}{freq=}\textcolor{purple}{<logische waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} } & {Histogram tekenen  Grootte van de balkjes aangeven, zie {$\leftarrow$}  \texttt{\textcolor{purple}{TRUE}}: plot de frequenties en \texttt{\textcolor{purple}{FALSE}}: plot verhouding tot geheel} & & {$\leftarrow$} \\
\\
\\
\texttt{layout()} &  \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{layout(}\textcolor{cyan}{<matrix>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Aanpassen van je grafische interface met de vorm van deze matrix} & & {$\leftarrow$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I have checked `longtable.dtx` and believe here is where the magic happens (lines 63-74):

```
\let\LT@@tabarray\@tabarray
\let\LT@@hl\hline
\def\@tabarray{%
\let\hline\LT@@hl
\let\multicolumn\LT@mcol
\LT@@tabarray}%
\let\\\LT@tabularcr\let\tabularnewline\\%
\def\newpage{\noalign{\break}}%
\def\pagebreak{\noalign{\ifnum`}=0\fi\@testopt{\LT@no@pgbk-}4}%
\def\nopagebreak{\noalign{\ifnum`}=0\fi\@testopt\LT@no@pgbk4}%
\let\hline\LT@hline \let\kill\LT@kill\let\caption\LT@caption
\@tempdima\ht\strutbox
\let\@endpbox\LT@endpbox
```

How can I and where should I add my line here? And as part of what argument? I tried `\def\newpage{...\<mycode>}`, but that wouldn't fly so well.

Comment: could you upload a draft of how will table look after? and also i don't think it's a good option to modify long table.dtx, i think is better just to define your special table with newcommand inside your own pack i.e. myTable.sty

Comment: @JaredLo I want the table to look exactly the way the `tabular` looks in my OP, except I want to do it automated with `longtable`, instead of `tabular`. I don't want to redefine `longtable.dtx`, I just want to maybe "hack" it to include that extra cell row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `longtable` supports to specify a headers and footer part, see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf).

Usually the space between two rows can be enlarged by the optional argument of `\\`. In this case the space gets first consumed by the large descenders of the text cells, therefore the example first ends the line and forbids a line break by `\\*`. Then it adds the space via `\noalign` and `\vskip` and adds a penalty to allow the linebreak. At a page break the space gets below the entry and not at the top of the new page.

An alternative is length `\extrarowheight`. This space is added above each row,
unfortunately it also affects the row in the header.

In the text columns the example uses `\RaggedRight` of package `raggedright` that allows hyphenation to smooth the ragging a bit. For justification the column width seems a little to small for me.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\tabsep}{3ex}
\newcommand*{\TS}{\noalign{\vskip\tabsep}\pagebreak[1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[h]{l >{\RaggedRight}p{5cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{5cm} c c} 
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector & Link
\\*\TS
\hline
\TS
\endhead
\texttt{?} & \texttt{?\textcolor{blue}{<commando>}} & {Het opzoeken van \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} commando's} && {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{apropos()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{apropos(}"\textcolor{cyan}{<commando>}"\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {(Deel van een) commando opzoeken} &  & {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{as.table()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{as.table(}\textcolor{cyan}{<array>}\textcolor{red}{)}} & {\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{R}} vertellen dat je de gegevens als een tabel wil lezen: read \texttt{as.table()}!} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{barplot()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{barplot(}\textcolor{cyan}{<functie>},} \texttt{\textcolor{green}{col=c(}\textcolor{red}{"<kleur>",...}\textcolor{green}{)}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Barplot maken (histogram, maar dan kolommen {apart}) Verschillende kleuren\label{anchor.kleurspec} instellen met de \textbf{engelse} namen, bijv.: \texttt{"brown"}} &  &
\\*\TS
\texttt{binom.test()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{binom.test(}\textcolor{cyan}{<tabel>},}  \texttt{\textcolor{green}{p=<waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Gesorteerde data tabel onderwerpen aan binomiaal test Hypothetische kans op succes (nulhypothese)} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{c()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{c(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},\textcolor{cyan}{ <getal>},\textcolor{red}{...}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Handmatig een array maken. Voor langere getallen, gebruik \texttt{array()}} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{colSums()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{colSums(}\textcolor{cyan}{<functie>}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Optellen van kolommen van een matrix. Voor rijen, gebruik: {\texttt{rowSums()}$\rightarrow$}} & $\surd$ & 
\\*\TS
\texttt{dbinom()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{dbinom(}\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>},} \texttt{\textcolor{green}{size=<waarde>},}  \texttt{\textcolor{red}{prob=<waarschijnlijkheid>}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Kans op deze waarde bij zovaak proberen kans op succes} & $\surd$ & {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{expand.grid()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{expand.grid(}}  \texttt{\textcolor{cyan}{<getal>}:\textcolor{green}{<getal>},\textcolor{red}{...}\textcolor{blue}{)}}} & {Aftellen meerdere dobbelstenen Minimale en maximale getal voor je `dobbelsteen'} &  & {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{file.choose()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{file.choose(}"\textcolor{cyan}{<bestand>}"\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Bestanden laden in \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}}} && {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{help()} & \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{help(}\textcolor{cyan}{<commando>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Het opzoeken van \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}} commando's} && {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{hist()} & {\texttt{\textcolor{blue}{hist(}\textcolor{cyan}{<functie>},}  \texttt{\textcolor{green}{breaks=}\textcolor{red}{<getal>},} \texttt{\textcolor{violet}{freq=}\textcolor{purple}{<logische waarde>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} } & {Histogram tekenen  Grootte van de balkjes aangeven, zie {$\leftarrow$}  \texttt{\textcolor{purple}{TRUE}}: plot de frequenties en \texttt{\textcolor{purple}{FALSE}}: plot verhouding tot geheel} & & {$\leftarrow$}
\\*\TS
\texttt{layout()} &  \texttt{\textcolor{blue}{layout(}\textcolor{cyan}{<matrix>}\textcolor{blue}{)}} & {Aanpassen van je grafische interface met de vorm van deze matrix} & & {$\leftarrow$}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]

> [image: Page 2]

Comment: Precisely what I wanted. I didn't find anything in the documentation on the usage of headers and footers in longtable, though? The search function within the manual didn't find any matches for "head" either...

Comment: I have fixed the example, it wasn't too "precise". `\endhead` and friends are described in section "3 Captions and Headings".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\tabpageskip}{

                        \newpage%

{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}}} code & Syntax & Gebruik & Is vector & Link \\
\\
\hline

                        }%

\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
\tabpageskip\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
\tabpageskip\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
a&b&C&D&E\\
\caption{Longtable}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know if you also want that the "tile row" automatic appears when long table computes a pagebreak

Comment: Obviously this is a solution, I was trying to circumvent a macro altogether and just redefine \newpage based on \section input.

Comment: inside longtable.dtx define the same command \tabpageskip \def\newpage{\noalign{\break}}

Comment: What I actually intended to do is to just use \newpage in the `longtable` environment and have this first line automatically added as a first row to the table. (*without* the use of a macro)